# How to await on an IAsyncOperation using C++/COM

Tags: async-await, com, windows-runtime, iasyncoperation

I am accessing a WinRT API using C++ and COM.

The following code gives me `results == unspecified`

```
ComPtr<IGeolocatorStatics> statics;
RoGetActivationFactory(HString::MakeReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geolocator).Get(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&statics));

ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<GeolocationAccessStatus>> op;
statics->RequestAccessAsync(&op);

GeolocationAccessStatus results;
op->GetResults(&results);
```

Whereas I get `results == allowed` from adding a `Sleep` call.

```
ComPtr<IGeolocatorStatics> statics;
RoGetActivationFactory(HString::MakeReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geolocator).Get(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&statics));

ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<GeolocationAccessStatus>> op;
statics->RequestAccessAsync(&op);

Sleep(100);

GeolocationAccessStatus results;
op->GetResults(&results);
```

Obviously, I need to either await on AsyncOperation to receive a callback when it is finished. I would prefer to do the former. How do I await on a WinRT IAsyncOperation from C++ using COM?

Comment: Why don't you use C++/WinRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency ?